# Building Mysql Workbench for Ubuntu Xenial Xerus

Tags: compiling, configure

I am trying build from source workbench 6.3 on Ubuntu 16.0.4, and can't seem to figure out how to start as I don't see the usual configure files, so the command `./configure` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow these instructions and see if it fits the bill.    http://mysqlworkbench.org/contribute/mysql-workbench-linux-build-instructions/